# sfdx force:data:soql:query - read SOQL query from a file

Tags: salesforcedx

So, let's say I have a windows batch file to dump an SObject into a CSV file:

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -u %1 -r csv -q ^
    "SELECT Name, PrimaryContact FROM Organization" ^
    > Organization.csv
```

While this works nicely I want the SOQL query to be read from the same CSV file before it gets overwritten with exported data. The SOQL query looks like this inside the file:

```
SELECT Name, PrimaryContact
FROM Organization
```

How can I provide sfdx with the SOQL from the file if SOQL statement contains newlines?

Comment: meaning the csv cell has a soft carriage return? or the csv has the query spanning two rows?

Comment: Use a scripting language that's a tad better than "Windows batch" and you'll be able to read the SOQL query from a file and then provide it to sfdx ([example in PowerShell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44920/extract-version-string-from-text-file-with-powershell))

Comment: There are several advantages to using a batch file for my use case. For simple use cases like this, I always try to keep it as simple as possible. The SOQL spans multiple rows (see example above).

Comment: StackOverflow has many Q&As on scripting with Windows cmd ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file)), have you tried asking there?

Comment: @identigral Sounds reasonable. While this is very specific for my use case it is probably a good idea to ask it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFDX has recently been updated and you can now use the `--soqlqueryfile` parameter to pull the SOQL query from a file